# Can the ionic function "ion-nav-view" (ui-router) work with ngRoute?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework, angular-routing

I am trying to merge the [Angularfire-Seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed) with a sample [Ionic App](http://ionicframework.com/). This has worked so far quite well.

To browse between my views, I am interested to use the ionic functionality:

```
// requires ui-router
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

instead of

```
// requires ngRoute
<div ng-view></div>
```

The problem is that the ion-nav-view (Ionic) is part of the ui-router ([see here explanation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)) whereas ng-view part of ngRoute (Angularfire-seed).

Is there therefore a way to keep using the `ngRoute` (as a lot of coding has been done in the Angularfire-Seed project and thus I dont want to switch to ui-router), but still use `ion-nav-view`?

Follow-up: has someone implemented AngularFire with Ionic (and thus ui-router)? Available git?

Comment: Try this Q&A where is working plunker with ionic example. It could help http://stackoverflow.com/a/25905602/1679310

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks like its mostly focused on ui-router isn't it?

Comment: Wanted to give you just something:) ui-router is the best choice anyhow...

Comment: ionic nav view needs ui-router, even the module dependency has ui.router. So you cannot use ng-route

Answer (score 1):

No, `ion-nav-view` uses the `ui-router` under the hood. Unless you want to write your own implementation you can't use `ngRoute` with it.

**EDIT**

To answer your question about using your linked file with Ionic,  you'll have to refactor it to use `ui-router`. Check the [UI Router Guide](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) here and the [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) here. It's well worth reading the first link to get a thorough understanding.

*Dependencies*

`ui-router` is included in the Ionic bundle so you don't need to explicitly state it as a dependency.

So provided you already have Ionic as a dependency, instead of

```
angular.module('myApp.routes', ['ngRoute', 'simpleLogin'])
```

you can just have

```
angular.module('myApp.routes', ['simpleLogin'])
```

*.config blocks*

I've not used `ngRoute` but the syntax between the `$stateProvider` of `ui-router` look quite similar. With `ngRoute` you used the `$routeProvider` like so...

```
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
   .when('/chat', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/chat.html',
    controller: 'ChatCtrl',
  })
```

With `ui-router` configuring a 'state' is something like the following (the use of `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise()` at the end catches any URLs that haven't been explicitly defined and redirects to whichever URL you specify)

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      resolve: {
        // resolve stuff in here, check the docs for implementation differences
      }
    })

    .state('chat', {
      url: '/chat',
      templateUrl: "partials/chat.html",
      controller: 'ChatCtrl',
      }
    })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Authentication is handled in your linked file, this link may help [angular ui-router login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22537311/angular-ui-router-login-authentication). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to replace ngRoute with ui-router in this file https://github.com/sibizavic/ionic-angularfire-mix/blob/master/js/routes.js