# Could not resolve '...' from state ''

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is first time i am trying to use ui-router.

Here is my app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index.html");

  $stateProvider.state('index', {
    url: '/'
    template: "index.html",
    controller: 'loginCtrl'
  });


  $stateProvider.state('register', {
    url: "/register"
    template: "register.html",
    controller: 'registerCtrl'
  });
})
```

As you can see, i have two states. I'm trying to register state like this:

```html
<a ui-sref="register">
  <button class="button button-balanced">
    Create an account
  </button>
</a>
```

But i am getting

> Could not resolve 'register' from state ''

exception. What is the problem here?

Comment: This is kind of silly, but I see you're creating the module 'myApp' and are listing 'ionic' as a dependency, however, I don't see 'ui-router' listed as a dependency. Are you including it somewhere else?

Comment: @deadbabykitten, ionic takes care of that.

Comment: @RogersSampaio - I just found that out recently, I had not used ionic before, but am using it for a mobile project now. It's pretty incredible.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This kind of error usually means that some parts of (JS) code were not loaded. That the state which is inside of `ui-sref` is missing.

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JpiliT6C6XGULRGQD6UF?p=preview)

*I am not an expert in ionic, so this example should show that it would be working, but I used some more tricks (parent for tabs)*

This is a bit adjusted state def:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index.html");

    $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "tpl.menu.html",
    })

  $stateProvider.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: "tpl.index.html",
    parent: "app",
  });


  $stateProvider.state('register', {
    url: "/register",
    templateUrl: "tpl.register.html",
    parent: "app",
  });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
```

And here we have the parent view with tabs, and their content:

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top">

  <ion-tab title="Index" icon="icon ion-home" ui-sref="index">
    <ion-nav-view name=""></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Register" icon="icon ion-person" ui-sref="register">
    <ion-nav-view name=""></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

*Take it more than an example of how to make it running and later use ionic framework the right way...Check that example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JpiliT6C6XGULRGQD6UF?p=preview)*

Here is similar Q & A with an example using the named views *(for sure better solution)* [ionic routing issue, shows blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25904197/1679310)

Improved version with named views in a tab is here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mj0rUxjLOXhHIelt249K?p=preview

```
  <ion-tab title="Index" icon="icon ion-home" ui-sref="index">
    <ion-nav-view name="index"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <ion-tab title="Register" icon="icon ion-person" ui-sref="register">
    <ion-nav-view name="register"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
```

targeting named views:

```
  $stateProvider.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    views: { "index" : { templateUrl: "tpl.index.html" } },
    parent: "app",
  });


  $stateProvider.state('register', {
    url: "/register",
    views: { "register" : { templateUrl: "tpl.register.html", } },
    parent: "app",
  });
```

Comment: My routes look ok, i checked other ionic examples and my code looks same. I put some debugger, console.log and alert into that config function and none of them executed. How can i make sure that my routes are loaded? can i see them somehow?

Comment: If I am curious to see what states are registered, I will typically inject $state info the .run() method. Then you can do console.log($states.get()) which will return an array of states.  

`.run ($state) {
    console.log($states.get());
});`

Answer (score 40):

Just came here to share what was happening to me.
You don't need to specify the parent, states work in an document oriented way so, instead of specifying parent: app, you could just change the state to app.index

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index.html");

$stateProvider.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "tpl.menu.html"
});

$stateProvider.state('app.index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: "tpl.index.html"
});

$stateProvider.state('app.register', {
    url: "/register",
    templateUrl: "tpl.register.html"
});
```

EDIT
Warning, if you want to go deep in the nesting, the full path must me specified. For example, you can't have a state like

```
app.cruds.posts.create
```

without having a

```
app
app.cruds
app.cruds.posts
```

or angular will throw an exception saying it can't figure out the rout. To solve that you can define abstract states

```
.state('app', {
     url: "/app",
     abstract: true
})
.state('app.cruds', {
     url: "/app/cruds",
     abstract: true
})
.state('app/cruds/posts', {
     url: "/app/cruds/posts",
     abstract: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks for `EDIT Warning, if you want to go deep in the nesting, the full path must me specified. For example, you can't have a state like`, that was my issue.

Comment: I had the same problem as above, but also wanted to include something in my state name path that wouldn't be reflected in the route path, so you can exclude the `url` property of the middle state, and then the following route `url` will be appended to the previous route url.

Answer (score 7):

I've just had this same issue with Ionic.

It turns out nothing was wrong with my code, I simply had to quit the ionic serve session and run ionic serve again.

After going back into the app, my states worked fine.

I would also suggest pressing save on your app.js file a few times if you are running gulp, to make sure everything gets re-compiled.

Comment: In my case restarting the server didn't solve the problem but helped me have a better error to debug. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with Ionic routing.

Simple solution is to use the name of the state - basically `state.go(state name)`

```
.state('tab.search', {
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      'tab-search': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

And in controller you can use `$state.go('tab.search');`

Answer (score 2):

I had a case where the error was thrown by a

```
$state.go('');
```

Which is obvious. I guess this can help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Magus :

> the full path must me specified

Abstract states can be used to add a prefix to all child state urls.
But note that **abstract still needs a ui-view for its children to populate**. To do so you can simply add it inline.

```
.state('app', {
   url: "/app",
   abstract: true,
   template: '<ui-view/>'
})
```

For more information see documentation : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views