# How to find all loaded routes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a function like this, supposed to load some routes.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider.state('app', {
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "index.html",
    })

  $stateProvider.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    views: { "index" : { templateUrl: "index.html" } },
    parent: "app",
  });

    $stateProvider.state('register', {
    url: "/register",
    views: { "register" : { templateUrl: "templates/register.html", } },
    parent: "app",
  });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
})
```

But i am getting

> Error: Could not resolve 'register' from state ''

exception. From all other examples i checked, that route config look fine. But it's not working some reason.

I suspect that my routes are not loaded, i put `console.log`, `debugger` and `alert` functions inside my `.config` function but none of them are executed.

Is there any way to list all loaded routes from ui-router?

Comment: Does the .js file that contains the .config() section get loaded? Did you include it in your index.html (or whatever HTML file loads all your scripts)?

Comment: @pbkhrv yes, that js file is loading with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Disclaimer: I would like to give you a hint. If this answer would not suite, let me know, will delete that. Because obviously, my previous answser is not working for you: [Could not resolve '...' from state ''](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28265230/1679310)

What could be the source of the error message like this?

> Could not resolve 'register' from state ''

There are only two options.

- File with the state definition is not loaded. *(Could be checked with some `console.log` stuff)*
- File represents `module` which is properly loaded, but not referenced by the root `ng-app="myApp"`

I would strongly expect, that the second case is the issue. Here is a [BROKEN example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gqaUxud0iCTNKBU1Hn8u?p=preview), which will (after button click) show the error: `Could not resolve 'register' from state ''`

What happened. There is a file called *"otherStates.js"*, which is loaded into *index.html*

...
      
      
   
   // see the scripts loaded above
   // below is the root module name "myApp"
   
   ...

The "otherStates.js" declares module "myStates", which contains all the states:

```
// will always be in a console
// because file is loaded
console.log("file is accessed");

angular
 .module('myStates', ['ionic'])
 .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    // never reach console, because this module is not used
    console.log("module myStates is not referenced in myApp ");
    console.log("these lines will never be trigerred");

  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
      abstract: true,
      ...
    })
  ....
```

So **Why** we do get that error? How to fix that?

Simply, in `script.js`, **(where is our root module)** we have this declaration:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
```

And that is not enough. We need to also reference the `myStates`. So we must change it like this and all will work

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'myStates'])
```

Check this [broken example](http://plnkr.co/edit/gqaUxud0iCTNKBU1Hn8u?p=preview)