# Require / Angular / Karma / ui-router - Error: Could not resolve 'landing' from state ''

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I've seen this symptom posted for other issues, and the closest that I have come to my issue is this Ionic issue:

[Could not resolve '...' from state ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265230/could-not-resolve-from-state)

**PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) Controller: ContainerCtrl test FAILED
    Error: Could not resolve 'landing' from state ''**

I am new to Karma testing for Angular, and having a hard time debugging a scope issue.

**app.js**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  // For any unmatched url, redirect to landing
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

  // Now set up the states
  $stateProvider
    .state('guide', {
      url: "/guide",
      templateUrl: "views/guide.html",
      controller: 'SurveyController as main'
    })
    .state('stop', {
      url: "/stop",
      templateUrl: "views/stop.html",
      controller: 'StopCtrl as stop'
    })
    .state('landing', {
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "views/landing.html",
      controller: 'AboutCtrl as about'
    });
});
```

**containerSpec.js**

```
define(['angular', 'angular-mocks', 'app'], function(angular, mocks, app) {
'use strict';

 describe('Controller: ContainerCtrl', function () {

  var ContainerCtrl, $state;

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app.controllers.ContainerCtrl', 'ui.router'));


    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller, _$state_) {
     //create an empty scope
     ContainerCtrl = $rootScope.$new();
     $state = _$state_;
     //declare the controller and inject our empty scope
     $controller('ContainerCtrl', { $scope : ContainerCtrl });

    }));

  });
});
```

**container.js**

```
define([
    'angular',
    'services/dataservice'], function (
        angular,
        dataService // jshint ignore:line
        ) {
'use strict';

angular.module('oslerApp.controllers.ContainerCtrl', [])
    .controller('ContainerCtrl', [
            '$scope',
            '$rootScope',
            '$state',
                function(
                    $scope,
                    $rootScope,
                    $state) {

            $state.go('landing');

    }]);
```

});

UPDATE:
Changing to logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG, I see that the load order of the Spec file is in advance of the app.js, and ui.router file.

```
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket B-PFcQHXMLMqx8cOoznu with id 19321969
DEBUG [launcher]: PhantomJS (id 19321969) captured in 4.068 secs
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /deploy/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/node_modules/requirejs/require.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/node_modules/karma-requirejs/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/test/test-main.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/bower_components/angular/angular.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/test/spec/controllers/containerSpec.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/test/spec/services/dataserviceSpec.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/app/scripts/app.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/app/scripts/services/dataservice.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /deploy/app/scripts/controllers/container.js
```

Comment: So $state in `containerSpec.js` is undefined?

Comment: It appears that way. Yes.

Comment: Oh, wait, you are trying to go to `landing` via your $state.go command, yet you haven't defined a state `landing` in your app.js. Address that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to go to the *landing* state via your `$state.go` command, yet you haven't defined a state *landing* in your app.js. Address that and see how you go.

Comment: I was trying to make this most vanilla by removing arbitrary wording ('landing') and using basic terms ('index'), but then forgot to make that change in the controller snippet. This lead us down the wrong path. Apologies. The state is defined correctly in my app.js.

Comment: So where does this leave you now?