# How to resolve error "undefined state from ***" in ui-router(Angularjs)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been developing a large MEAN stack based web application , and using ui-router as one of module in angular frontend.

I am constantly getting error in console : "Error: Could not resolve 'undefined' from state 'advertiser.home' " .

Can anyone tell me steps to find out the issue ? I cant post my code here as Its confidential project.

Comment: Without code we cannot found your exact error

Comment: Yep. Please post some code!

Comment: It is not necessary to post your entire "confidential project".  However, it *is* necessary to post at least some code showing your configuration relating to the error you are trying to troubleshoot.  Without code to review, you are essentially asking others to make blind guesses at your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not resolve '...' from state ''](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265230/could-not-resolve-from-state)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the state which is inside of `ui-sref` is not missing.

Detailed solution is
[here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265230/could-not-resolve-from-state)