# angular.min.js:117 Error: Could not resolve 'create' from state ''

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

Hi I have created a angularjs+webix project wherein I will be adding CRUD operations.

I have a app.js file where I put the routing:

```
var app =  angular.module('app', [ "webix", "ui.router" ]);

app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    
    .state("/create", {
        templateUrl : "/app/views/CreateTemplate.html",
        controller : 'CreateController'
    })

    .state("/update", {
        templateUrl : "/app/views/UpdateTemplate.html",
        controller : 'UpdateController'
    })
    
    .state("/delete", {
        templateUrl : "/app/views/DeleteTemplate.html",
        controller : 'DeleteController'
    })
});
```

My index.html file below:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  
  <div class="container">

    <div class="sidenav">
      <a ui-sref="create">Create</a>
      <a ui-sref="update">Update</a>
      <a ui-sref="delete">Delete</a>
    </div>


  </div>

</body>
```

My index file contains a navbar. Whenever I click on either Create or Update it should show that particular view i.e. If I click on Create It should load Create view. But in doing so I am unsuccessful.

Comment: Did you check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265230/could-not-resolve-from-state?

Comment: Yes I did. But the issue still persists with CORS issue.

Comment: The solutions to CORS issues are very straightforward and among the most well documented. Search for solutions along those lines and you should have a resolution quickly.